# Leaflet package in R not plotting all coordinates

Tags: r, mapping, leaflet

I'm trying to plot using leaflet with a somewhat sizable set of coordinates (~34K latitude/longitude pairs) however, using the code below it seems that leaflet is only plotting a small portion of these:

```
data <- read.csv("Food_inspections.csv", header = TRUE)
names(data) <- tolower(names(data))
data1 <- filter(data, risk == c("Risk 1 (High)","Risk 2 (Medium)","Risk 3 (Low)"))
data1$risk <- droplevels(data1$risk)

leaflet(data1) %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    addMarkers(lat = ~latitude, lng = ~longitude)
```

What I get back is a map like this:

[image: leaflet map]

This clearly does not contain all ~34K coordinates. Even if I use "addCircles" I get the same thing. Other mapping packages (RgoogleMaps for instance) seem to plot everything correctly. Does leaflet round the coordinates it takes as input before plotting because I could see that making several of the coordinates appear to overlap in the plot.

Comment: Doesn't the result displayed in the browser allow you to zoom in and out?

Comment: Chicago food inspections... a hot topic lately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The points are there, you  have to zoom in to see them. But... at least in my browser... anything more than 80 points or so, and it takes super long to zoom.

```
url <- "http://data.cityofchicago.org/api/views/4ijn-s7e5/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD"
data <- read.csv(url, header = TRUE) # takes a minute...
names(data) <- tolower(names(data))
data1 <- subset(data, risk %in% c("Risk 1 (High)","Risk 2 (Medium)","Risk 3 (Low)"))
data1$risk <- droplevels(data1$risk)

data1 <- data1[1:50,]
library(leaflet)
leaflet(data1) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(lat = ~latitude, lng = ~longitude)
```